# how we can calculate $ \frac {\sqrt {x^2} + \sqrt {y^2} }{2 \sqrt {xyz}}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math, education

I teach math for Schools. How can Help me in the following past Olympiad question?

> If $y,z$ be two negative distinct number and $x$ and $y$ be negate of each other, how we can calculate $ \displaystyle\frac {\sqrt {x^2} + \sqrt {y^2} }{2 \sqrt {xyz}}$?
>
> 1) $\frac {\sqrt{x}}{x}$
>
> 2)$\frac {\sqrt{-y}}{y}$
>
> 3) $\frac {\sqrt{z}}{z}$
>
> 4) $\frac {\sqrt{-z}}{-z}$

Comment: The answer is $\frac1{\sqrt{-z}}$ no?

Comment: $\sqrt{a^2}=|a|$.

Comment: @GregoryGrant is not in the choice

Comment: Note that $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$.  So since $y=-x$ the top is $2|x|$ and the denominator is $2\sqrt{-x^2z}$ which equals $2|x|\sqrt{-z}$.  So everything cancels but the $\sqrt{-z}$ in the denominator.  Where's the mistake?

Comment: @LoveMathContest What are the choices?

Comment: The last answer is equivalent to those given below.

Comment: Ah note that  $\frac{1}{\sqrt{-z}}=\frac{\sqrt{-z}}{-z}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$.  So since $y=-x$ the top is $2|x|$ and the denominator is $2\sqrt{-x^2z}$ which equals $2|x|\sqrt{-z}$.  So everything cancels but the $\sqrt{-z}$ in the denominator.  Now multiply top and bottom by $\sqrt{-z}$ to get $\frac{\sqrt{-z}}{-z}$

Comment: see edited questions

Comment: @LoveMathContest I edited my answer, should be complete now.

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac{\sqrt{x^2}+\sqrt{y^2}}{2\sqrt{xyz}}=\frac{2\sqrt{x^2}}{2\sqrt{-x^2z}}$$ using $y=-x$. This yields: $$\frac{2\sqrt{x^2}}{2\sqrt{x^2}\sqrt{-z}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{-z}}$$. Note that $z<0$, so $-z>0$, so $\sqrt{-z}$ is well-defined.

Comment: I said the same thing but he says that's not one of the choices.  I've asked for clarification.

Comment: @GregoryGrant Ah, I missed the discussion while writing my answer. Thanks for the comment. I agree with your answer.

Comment: He edited the question, turns out we're both right.  I'll upvote your answer.

Comment: @GregoryGrant Likewise, since we have the same thing.